# Is there a Java Map implementation that supports 2 keys?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Is there some type of map implementation that supports 2 separate keys?
For example you would do something like `put(Int, String, Value)` and then you'd later be able to use get the value based on the Integer or the String independently. Currently I am just using 2 Maps but it seems like there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: Wrap the two maps up in a single class that contains them both?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question: No.

You could roll it yourself:

```java
class MyDataStore<T> {
    private final Map<Integer, T> intMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, T> stringMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(Integer keyI, String keyS, T datum) {
        intMap.put(keyI, datum);
        stringMap.put(keyS, datum);
    }

    public void remove(T datum) {
        intMap.remove(datum);
        stringMap.remove(datum);
    }

    public Map<Integer, T> asIntMap() {return Collections.unmodifiableMap(intMap);}
    public Map<String, T> asStringMap() {return Collections.unmodifiableMap(stringMap);}
}
```

Though a lot depends upon your use case. Maybe it's ok to key by one thing, and do an incremental search for the other? Especially if you don't actually have many elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<Object, MyValueClass>` and store the value under both keys.

If you really want a class:

```
public class DoubleKeyMap<T> extends HashMap<Object, T> {
    public void put(Object key1, Object key2, T value) {
        put(key1, value);
        put(key2, value);
    }
}
```

The value can now be found under either key.